# Laravel 4 Response download issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to force a download of a zip file that contains a few PDFS.

```
return Response::download($zipperPath, NULL, array('content-type' => 'application/zip'));
```

This will force the download.. however the files are corrupted. If I repair the zip it fixes the issue with the re-built zip. I am not sure if maybe I am missing something in the headers or if this is an issue with Laravel?

any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Check that the mime-type is set to octet-stream also perhaps check that there there isn't anything strange happening with gzip during the download.

Comment: try to check this: Symfony HttpFoundation, which manages file downloads, requires the file being downloaded to have an ASCII file name.

Answer (score 7):

```
$response = Response::download($file, NULL, $headers);
ob_end_clean();
return $response;
```

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2892

Comment: I had the same issue in Laravel 5.2. Calling the ob_end_clean() fixed it. The strange thing was that it was working fine for months without ob_end_clean() and then suddenly stopped. I spend a week to try to fix it. Finally that was the fix. Thanks a lot!