# Downloading zip file results in .cpgz file after extraction

Tags: download, laravel-5, zip

I am using the following code do download a zip file. I am sure the file is existing and working on the server. The result is .cpgz file after extraction.

```
  return response()->download('/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/stoproject/source/storage/app/Copy of StoTherm Classic®.zip');
```

The code was working and without any change, it stopped.

I also tried adding headers:

```
$headers = array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/zip',
        );

return response()->download('/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/stoproject/source/storage/app/Copy of StoTherm Classic®.zip', basename('/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/stoproject/source/storage/app/Copy of StoTherm Classic®.zip'), $headers);
```

Also tried with:

```
'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling ob_end_clean() fixed the issue

```
$response = response()->download($pathToFile)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);

ob_end_clean();

return $response;
```

[Laravel 4 Response download issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481546/laravel-4-response-download-issue)